# Plotting data using matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot, series

I have to plot this data with matlab but I can't correctly import the date-time column.
How can I do?
Thanks for the answers.

09/10/2000 16:30:00 981.5
09/10/2000 17:00:00 981.2344
09/10/2000 17:30:00 981.2188
09/10/2000 18:00:00 981.2031
.....(other 1800 data)

Comment: How are you importing the non datetime data?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) function to convert from a date string to a numeric value. If you are importing the data from Excel, you may want to read [When to Convert Dates from Excel Files](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/import_export/when-to-convert-dates-from-excel-files.html)

Comment: +1, I'll add `datetick` to the list of useful commands to try :)